# SQL Joining two different queries that use only one table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Basically, I have a table that contains employee information:

**frs_Employee**

[image]

My end result should be a query that returns the managers' names (people that don't have a 'mngnin', i.e. the first 12 employees), with the names of the employees they manage.

I've figured out how to return the concatenated list of employees:

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(empname) AS employees)
FROM frs_Employee 
WHERE `mgrnin` <> ''
GROUP BY `mgrnin`
```

The problem lies in that one of the managers (NIN001) doesn't manage an employee. Hence, when I use the GROUP BY, I have one less rows than I should. 
I either need to get the GROUP BY to somehow get the empty field as well - I tried using an alias like:

```
(SELECT `empnin` FROM frs_Employee WHERE `mgrnin` = '') AS `myAlias`
```

but that's a whole headache on its own.

I also tried using a JOIN (which is how I suspect this is solved), but I can't wrap my mind around it. I also thought about using a temporary table, but I'm not sure exactly to accomplish that.

Any ideas for a good, universal solution?

Comment: The relation is only parent -> child or it can have grandparent->parent->child and so on ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos for description looks like only the ones with null are managers

Comment: yeah, I understood that. I asked because it is a common mistake from new guys to not consider the depth of a relation. It was just to be sure. within one level a plain left join solves the problem but if it is more then one like `John manages Peter that manages Phill` in mysql it is not so trivial.

Comment: It's only one level deep - parent -> child

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with a `left join`:

```
SELECT m.empnin, GROUP_CONCAT(e.empname) AS employees
FROM frs_Employee m LEFT JOIN
     frs_Employee e
     ON e.mgrnin = m.empnin 
WHERE m.mgrnin IS NULL
GROUP BY m.empin;
```

Notice also that no subquery is required for the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't give me the answer I need. It just returns the managers and their id.